# git branch roll back to previous commits

Tags: git, branch, rollback

I have got two  branches (master and secondary) at most recent commit. I need the older commit ed state ( 2 unit backward) and so want my secondary branch to move back two commits.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 6):

```
git branch -f secondary secondary~2
```

This will only change the commit which the branch references and does not interact with the worktree. as such it's a bit safer than going the `git reset` route. It will not work if the branch is currently checked out, but this is easily solved by switching to another branch, creating a temporary branch, or detaching HEAD (`git checkout HEAD^{}`). Another possibility would be to use `git checkout -B secondary secondary~2`, but this will change your worktree.

don't do this, if your `secondary` branch was already pushed and was publicly available